# python import relative path 'No module found error'

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-import

I am in folder2 trying to execute **trigger.py**

I used:

```
from ..folder1.subfolder1.function1 import *
from ..folder1.test.py
```

got error attempted relative import with no known parent package

[image]

Comment: How do you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running out of `folder2`, then for all practical purposes, `trigger.py` is a module on its own, not part of a package hierarchy, and can't use relative imports to `folder1` (because they're unrelated).

If you can, make your working directory the parent directory of `Project`, and invoke your script with:

```
python3 -m Project.folder2.trigger
```

which runs a module as the main entry point via import syntax, without losing the information on the package structure.

If the whole project is actually installed to system or user `site-packages`, your working directory won't matter (it's only needed if it's not in `sys.path` automatically, because the working directory itself is included in `sys.path`), and the invocation will work anywhere.